# How to find which one is master/slave? - PIC

Tags: pic, i2c, eeprom

Im using PIC24FJ64GA002 microcontroller interfacing with EEPROM(24C256). EEPROM's SDA and SCL pins are connected with respective PIC24F I2C1's SDA and SCL. All other pins of eeprom are grounded. Here i have EEPROM address that is 0xA0. Now, how to find which one is slave and master? Is PIC or eeprom? I've heard which has clock that is a master. Both have clock pins.

[image]

Comment: The PIC is the master. The EEPROM is the slave. Thee EEPROM datsheet should say something like "this is an I2C slave device."

Comment: Or it can be deduced from the timing diagrams describing read/write cycles. Or just using logic.

Comment: @ThePhoton Hi. It didnt mention in the datasheet. Thanks for the reply...

Comment: @IMGP007, which 24C256 device are you using? Please provide a link to the datasheet.

Comment: @ThePhoton AT24C256 ATMEL [link]https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAAahUKEwjbt5Tehd7HAhXICBoKHb7aCmI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.atmel.com%2FImages%2Fdoc0670.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHtcT6MZJ7zfRP8BcNfMfSWHZo6Sw&sig2=Z-Q0agrvu-bpfROkrY9tJQ&bvm=bv.101800829,bs.1,d.bGQ

Comment: Atmel is very stubborn about paying NXP for the right to use the name "I2C", so it looks like they've decided they can't use the words "master" or "slave" either. I agree it doesn't make the datasheet very clear. One clue is on page 10, where it talks about "the addressing device, such as a microcontroller" (unfortunately this is somewhat buried in a discussion of the write transaction).

Comment: Stop and actually *think* about how this has to work.  It should be obvious, even without the EEPROM data sheet, that the EEPROM *must* be the slave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EEPROM is the slave.

In the On Semi [24C256 datasheet](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/CAT24C256-D.PDF), for example, it says

> The CAT24C26 acts as a Slave device.

However it should be obvious that this is the case, because the EEPROM has no idea what I2C address the PIC is using, nor which storage address should be read or written, until it is told, and the master is responsible for providing this information.

Also, under I2C, only the slave has an address. Since the EEPROM has an address (often even called a "slave address") it is clear the EEPROM acts as the I2C slave.

Comment: I wonder what would be the use of a Master EEPROM...